# How to debug systemd-networkd?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, systemd

I would like to use `systemd-networkd` to configure my networking on Ubuntu.

I added an `/etc/systemd/network/host0.network` file

```
[Match]
Name=host0

[Network]
Address=10.5.1.1/24
Gateway=10.5.1.254
```

to configure my `host0`:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: host0@if14428: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:fa:2e:69:dd:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.229.86/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link host0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d4fa:2eff:fe69:dd30/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But, as seen above it is not configured with `10.5.1.1` despite restarting `systemd-networkd`, enabling it, rebooting. Each time the address is from APIPA (as if there was no DHCP, which is not configured there).

In no other places is networking configured (notably in `/etc/network/interfaces`, which is empty)

Comment: Did you look at the output of `networkctl` yet? What about `systemctl status systemd-networkd`?

Comment: This is years old by now, but just to point out that the `.network` file goes in `/etc/systemd/network/host0.network` (not the typo'ed `netwoek`)

Comment: Thanks @RalphBolton - never too late to correct an error :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/network-config-with-networkd.html :

### Enable debugging manually

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/
```

Create Drop-In `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/10-debug.conf` with following content:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

And restart `systemd-networkd` service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd
```

Comment: `systemctl edit systemd-networkd` is slightly faster as it creates automatically the needed folder and doesn't need daemon-reload.

Comment: For some reason I had to reboot before debugging was activated for systemd-networkd. Just mentioning it in case someone else struggles. (Yes, I tried reloading and restarting - multiple times.) Running systemd 243.

Comment: Will I be able to open the log with a regular text editor? i.e. - what is the name and the location of this file?

Comment: @GuyAvraham the log goes to the (binary) journal so you will have to use the journalctl command stated to view it.

Answer (score 4):

> How to debug systemd-networkd?

### activate debug logging using `service-log-level`

You can leverage [`systemctl`'s **`service-log-level`** command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#service-log-level%20SERVICE%20%5BLEVEL%5D):

```sh
# set current log level of systemd-networkd.service to "debug":
systemctl service-log-level systemd-networkd.service debug
```

```sh
# syntax:
# systemctl service-log-level SERVICE [LEVEL]
# LEVEL:
# a value in the range 0…7
# or one of the strings emerg, alert, crit, err, warning, notice, info, debug
```

```sh
# check current log level of systemd-networkd.service by not specifying a level:
systemctl service-log-level systemd-networkd.service
```

### monitor/see `systemd-networkd.service` logs

*journald*'s `systemd-networkd.service`-specific log entries can then be monitored with:

```sh
journalctl --unit=systemd-networkd.service --follow

# or short
journalctl -u systemd-networkd -f
```

Example *journald* log entries with "*systemd-networkd log on debug level*" when executing `networkctl renew eth0` on my system:

```
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: Got message type=method_call sender=:1.31 destination=org.freedesktop.network1 path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.network1.Manager member=RenewLink cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=i error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=GetConnectionUnixUser cookie=59 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.15 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=17 reply_cookie=59 signature=u error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=:1.31 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=60 reply_cookie=2 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: DHCP CLIENT (0x359abcde): REQUEST (renewing)
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: DHCP CLIENT (0x359abcde): ACK
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: DHCP CLIENT (0x359abcde): lease expires in 59min 58s
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: DHCP CLIENT (0x359abcde): T2 expires in 49min 25s
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: DHCP CLIENT (0x359abcde): T1 expires in 26min 54s
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: State changed: configured -> configuring
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=61 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: Updating address: 10.0.3.165
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: Remembering updated address: 10.0.3.165/24 (valid for 1h)
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: link_check_ready(): static routes are not configured.
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: DHCP: No routes received from DHCP server: No data available
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: Configuring route: dst: 10.0.3.1/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 10.0.3.165, scope: link, table: main, proto: dhcp, type: unicast
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: Configuring route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 10.0.3.1, prefsrc: 10.0.3.165, scope: global, table: main, proto: dhcp, type: unicast
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: link_check_ready(): dhcp4:no dhcp6_addresses:no dhcp_routes:no dhcp_pd_addresses:no dhcp_pd_routes:no ndisc_addresses:yes ndisc_routes:yes
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: eth0: State changed: configuring -> configured
Sep 08 13:45:43 abdull systemd-networkd[572]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=62 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
```

Whereas when `systemd-networkd.service` is on the default `info` log level, there are no log entries when when executing `networkctl renew eth0` on my system.

### Comparison between *this* `service-log-level` solution and the [*drop-in* solution](https://superuser.com/a/1234599/137881):

|  | `service-log-level` | *drop-in* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| requires/implies `systemctl daemon-reload` | no ✔️ | yes ❌ |
| requires `systemd-networkd.service` restart | no ✔️ | yes ❌ |
| configuration persists after `systemd-networkd.service` | no ❌ | yes ✔️ |
| configuration persists after computer reboot | no ❌ | yes ✔️ |
| easy oneliner for turning debugging on and off | yes ✔️ | no ❌ |

Note: checkmark (✔️) and chrossmark (❌) characters indicate desirable or undesirable trait (depending on context).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are great to find out what is running and what isn't, and restarting the service.

I'd add (from [How to enable if it's disabled](https://askubuntu.com/posts/681768/revisions)):

```
systemctl enable <your.service.here>
```

e.g. `systemd-networkd`

Also, I'm not sure what `Name=host0` matches. I guess something, since it shows up in `2: host0@if14428` under `ip addr`. But using and interface name, or MAC address, as it appears in `ip link` is a safer bet.

Comment: `host0` is in fact an interface name -- it's the default name on systemd-nspawn containers for the "inside" half of a veth pair.

Comment: this is a useless answer, if i were you i'd remove it

Comment: @nhed Indeed, it is so useless, that I even refuse to downvote, as it is not worth that price.