# nslookup failed but systemd-resolved works

Tags: ubuntu, dns, systemd, resolv.conf

This is a strange problem I've spent all day on. It would be great if someone could shed some light on this.

The problem exhibits as a problem with name resolution, but I'm not sure that's the root cause:

```
# host www.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

so far so boring, but wait!:

```
#systemd-resolve www.google.com
www.google.com: 209.85.202.103
                209.85.202.106
                209.85.202.105
                209.85.202.104
                209.85.202.147
                209.85.202.99
```

Simple, the problem is with resolv.conf right?

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.53

search xxx.uk xyz
```

So the system is using the systemd resolver?

```
#dig @127.0.0.53 www.google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.53 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

ok, so if the systemd resolver says it's on 127.0.0.53 why is it not responding.

```
#sudo netstat -lupn | grep 127
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1679/systemd-resolv
```

If it's not listening, what is systemd-resolv doing?

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 20 (veth10858e2)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 14 (vnet0)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 13 (virbr0-nic)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 12 (virbr0)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 11 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 10 (docker_gwbridge)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (em2)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.100.1
                      192.168.100.2
                      192.168.100.3
                      192.168.100.4
          DNS Domain: cqp

Link 2 (em1)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: xxx.xxx.x.xx
                      xxx.xxx.x.xx
          DNS Domain: xxx.uk
```

I have several severs, they're all running up to date ubuntu artful, this problem has moved between servers in the process of trying to fix this.
 They are part of a docker swarm and removing, then re-adding fix the problem at one point.

---

I turned on [systemd-resolved debugging](https://superuser.com/questions/1187633/how-to-debug-systemd-networkd) but there was no output when a request was made.

Comment: Perhaps your firewall is blocking it?

Comment: You might be right, but I can't see a rule which would affect it - what I don't understand is how is the system deciding what to ask, I thought that it read resolv.conf for where to send the request

Comment: nslookup is not "the system". systemd-resolvectl is not "the system". They both use a more direct approach than "the system" does, and they both use different APIs (systemd-resolvectl uses D-Bus, not UDP.)

Comment: I know that it ultimately boils down to gethostbyname(), which is what is failing, how does that decide how to resolve the address if it's not using 127.0.0.53 as resolve.conf says?

Comment: My point was that **it doesn't** boil down to gethostbyname(). The `nslookup` tool still uses resolv.conf but actually speaks DNS directly. And the `systemd-resolve` tool does not speak DNS at all, it speaks D-Bus.

Answer (score 11):

I found [this answer on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17042047) which suggested symlinking `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

That worked for me. I don't think I had to restart any services after recreating the symlink.

Comment: Thanks but this is already the case.

Comment: @Richard Collins: So this is not the answer?

Comment: No, there might be some link with an issue with docker and firewalld - there's no hard evidence for that though

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds crazy, but you need to allow access to `127.0.0.53` to use `systemd-resolved`

```
iptables -I INPUT -s localhost -d 127.0.0.53  -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether resolv.conf file is available in the file path: `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

It is Symbolic linked with `/etc/resolv.conf`

If the file is not available then create it in this file location `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and delete the file in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Now relink the file by cmd `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Now try to ping, it will fix the issue most