# DNSChef practice, "communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused"

Tags: linux, networking, dns, kali-linux

In Kali Linux, I face an issue while trying to implement/practice DNSChef on my VirtualBox, following the description [here](https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef).

For:

```
host -t A thesprawl.org
```

I get:

> ;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
> ;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
> thesprawl.org has address 216.239.38.21

While seeking a fix, I found this and I've set the symlink as described here:
[nslookup failed but systemd-resolved works](https://superuser.com/questions/1317623/nslookup-failed-but-systemd-resolved-works).

But it doesn't work for this case. I'd be very thankful for a hand, how should I get it to run properly.

My Kali has the latest updates and upgrades.