systemd-networkd "DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER" until manual dhclient invocation
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS server with network managed by networkd and netplan.
I have a well-behaved interface wlp2s0 which gets a DHCPv4 configuration within ~2 seconds, as expected. However enp4s0 which is connected to the same network does not.
$  journalctl --since "3 minutes ago" | sed -n 's/.*enp4s0: //p'
NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 1min 2s
DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 2min
DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER

(detailed logs thanks to https://superuser.com/a/1234599/82589 )
The configuration for these only differs in RouteMetric
$ sudo diff -y -W 56 /run/sy*/netw*/*
[Match]                         [Match]
Name=enp4s0                |    Name=wlp2s0

[Network]                       [Network]
DHCP=ipv4                       DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6        LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]                          [DHCP]
RouteMetric=100            |    RouteMetric=600
UseMTU=true                     UseMTU=true
$ sudo cat /etc/netp*/* | grep -B3 -A3 enp4s0
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp4s0:
            dhcp4: true
    wifis:
        wlp2s0:

Running dhclient instantly works:
$ sudo dhclient && journalctl --since "3 minutes ago" | sed -n 's/.*enp4s0: //p'
DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
Received new foreign address (configured): 192.168.1.43/24 broadcas[...]
Received new foreign route (configured): dst: 192.168.1.43/32, src:[...]
Received new foreign route (configured): dst: 192.168.1.255/32, src[...]
Received new foreign route (configured): dst: 192.168.1.0/24, src: [...]
Received new foreign route (configured): dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 19[...]

Why does dhclient succeed where networkd's built-in client fails? What piece of configuration am I missing? I've had multiple interfaces on the same network before, but only with Network-Manager, is that part of the issue?
